# Rails error in test driven development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am following the tutorial of [Michael Harlt](http://ruby.railstutorial.org) .And i am a newbie of web development.

SO i am facing many error while writing test .  I am sharing the errors log and i  have searched a  on internet and looked a lot toward my code but not getting what is the error so please help me i am sharing both the code and the error log. 

Code of spec file.`

```
require 'spec_helper'


 describe "Static pages" do
        subject{ page }



  describe "Home page" do
        before {visit root_path}

        it { should have_selector('h1',  text: 'Sample App')}
        it {should have_selector ('title',  text: full_title(''))}
       it { should_not have_selector 'title',  text: '|Home'}
   end


describe "Help page" do
         before {visit help_path}

         it { should have_selector('h1',        text:'Help')}
         it { should have_selector('title',     text: full_title('Help'))}

end
    describe "About page"do
          before {visit about_path}

          it {should have_selector('h1',       text:'About')}
          it {should have_selector('title',     text: full_title('About US'))}
    end

  describe "Contact page" do
           before { visit contact_path}

           it {should have_selector('h1',       text:'Contact')}
           it{should have_selector('title',     text: full_title('Contact'))}
  end
end
```

Code for the methode `full_title()`

```
   module ApplicationHelper
         def full_title(page_title)
        base_title="Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
         if page_title.empty?
         base_title
         else
        "#{base_title} | #{page_title} "
         end
         end

   end
```

And the error log  is

after executing command bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

`it {should have_selector('title',title: full_title(''))}
                                                       ^`

**C:/sample_app/spec/request/static_pages_spec.rb:15 syntax error,unexpected keyword_end,expecting '}'**
****C:/sample_app/spec/request/static_pages_spec.rb:15 syntax error,unexpected keyword_end,expecting '}'****

spec_helper file for @spullen

```
require 'spec_helper'
  describe StaticPagesHelper do
      pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
  end
```

Comment: Indenting code is quite easy, and crucial in understanding it. Please take a few minutes to indent and outdent appropriately so we (and you) can see what is going on without undue mental load to remember dos and ends.

Comment: What's the error? What does your spec_helper look like? If `full_title` that's the problem after `require 'spec_helper'` add include ApplicationHelper to see if it fixes it.

Comment: @spullen i am sharing the spec_helper wait

Comment: @coreyward yes why not i am indenting wait

Comment: The problem looks like it might be due to indentation and spacing.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, I'd look into getting/using an editor with support for Ruby which will help you  avoid syntax errors and reduce the effort of maintaining proper indenting.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin so please tell me the name of editor

Comment: @jahanzaibjahanzaib it depends on your environment. I use Sublime Text 2, but you should Google for the options

Comment: Thanks all but i still haven't got the solution so please someone there to resolve this issue.